Categories in which isomorphism of stalks does not imply isomorphism of sheaves
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a locally small category with colimits of small filtered diagrams.
For the purposes of this question, an $\mathcal{A}$-presheaf on a topological space $X$ is a functor $\Omega (X)^\textrm{op} \to \mathcal{A}$, where $\Omega (X)$ is the poset of open subspaces of $X$, and an $\mathcal{A}$-sheaf is an $\mathcal{A}$-presheaf $A$ such that, for all objects $T$ in $\mathcal{A}$, $U \mapsto \mathcal{A} (T, A (U))$ is a sheaf (of sets).
The stalk $A_x$ of an $\mathcal{A}$-presheaf $A$ at a point $x$ is the colimit $\varinjlim_U A (U)$ where $U$ varies over the filter of open neighbourhoods of $x$.
Say $\mathcal{A}$ is sheaf-local on a topological space $X$ if, for every morphism $f : A \to B$ of $\mathcal{A}$-sheaves on $X$, if $f_x : A_x \to B_x$ is an isomorphism in $\mathcal{A}$ for all points $x$ in $X$, then $f$ is an isomorphism (of $\mathcal{A}$-sheaves on $X$).
It is well known that common categories such as $\textbf{Set}$, $\textbf{Ab}$, $\textbf{CRing}$ and so on are sheaf-local on every topological space.
In fact, this is so for any finitely accessible category.
It is also clear that sheaf-locality on a discrete space is automatic.
Question.
What are some examples of $\mathcal{A}$ and $X$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is not sheaf-local on $X$?
If we generalise to (∞, 1)-categories, then topological spaces that do not have enough points in the ∞-topos sense would provide examples.
But I wonder if this phenomenon already happens at the 1-category level.
(This is somewhat related to my old question, is there a good general definition of "sheaves with value in a category"?)

I wonder if the answers given here now also answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4141460/example-where-the-associated-sheaf-does-not-exist

The specific categories mentioned should have sheafification functors – for locally presentable categories it is an application of a general result for orthogonality classes, and for the category of complete join semilattices it can be justified by thinking about $\kappa$-ary join semilattices and noting that the sheafification for any particular presheaf stabilises for large enough $\kappa$.

One tends to run into non-conservativity of stalks when working with sheaves of categories with colimits. There are some remarks in the literature about this point, for sheaves valued in the $\infty$-category of presentable stable $\infty$-categories, see for instance https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04291 remark 2.8.2.
The $\infty$ is not really essential: we can adapt all that to get an example of a 1-category $\mathcal{A}$ which does the job. Namely, let $\mathcal{A}$ be the category whose objects are small posets with all joins, and whose morphisms are order preserving maps which commute with joins. It then turns out that for sheaves on $\mathbb{R}$ valued in $\mathcal{A}$, taking stalks does not detect isomorphisms.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the $\mathcal{A}$-valued sheaf on $\mathbb{R}$ which assigns to each open set $U$ the poset of open subsets of $U$, where for each pair of opens $U \subseteq V$ the restriction $i_{U, V}^*: \mathcal{F}(V) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(U)$ is given by intersection with $U$. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the subsheaf of $\mathcal{F}$ which sends each open set $U$ to the poset of open subsets of $U$ which are unions of connected components of $U$. I claim that the inclusion $\mathcal{G} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ induces an isomorphism in stalks.
Fix a point $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Then the stalk of $\mathcal{G}$ at $x$ can be computed as the colimit of $\mathcal{G}((x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon))$ over all $\varepsilon > 0$. This is a constant diagram with value given by the poset $\lbrace 0 < 1 \rbrace$, so the stalk $\mathcal{G}_x$ is given by $\lbrace 0 < 1 \rbrace$.
General results about colimits of locally presentable categories imply that the stalk of $\mathcal{F}$ at $x$ can be computed as the limit $\lim_{U} \mathcal{F}(U)$, where once again we index over all neighborhoods of $x$, but where for each inclusion $U \subseteq V$ the transition in the diagram is given by the morphism of posets $(i_{U, V})_*: \mathcal{F}(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(V)$ which is right adjoint to $i_{U, V}^*$. The maps $(i_{U, V})_*$ are all fully faithful, and hence the stalk of $\mathcal{F}$ at $x$ can be computed as the intersection of the images of $(i_{U, \mathbb{R}})_*$ over all neighborhoods $U$ of $x$. An open subset $W$ of $\mathbb{R}$ in the image of $(i_{U, \mathbb{R}})_*$ necessarily contains the complement of $U$, so we see that the intersection of all these images consists of at most two elements, namely $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}-\lbrace x \rbrace$. Both are realized: for any $U$ we have that $\mathbb{R} = (i_{U, \mathbb{R}})_*(U)$, while $\mathbb{R} - \lbrace x \rbrace = (i_{U, \mathbb{R}})_*(U - \lbrace x \rbrace)$. It follows that the stalk of $\mathcal{F}$ at $x$ is also given by the poset $\lbrace 0 < 1 \rbrace$.
We now have that the stalk of both $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ at $x$ is given by $\lbrace 0 < 1 \rbrace$. The morphism $\mathcal{G}_x \rightarrow \mathcal{F}_x$ preserves minimum elements since it is a morphism in $\mathcal{A}$. The only thing left to observe is that the morphism $\mathcal{G}_x \rightarrow \mathcal{F}_x$ is not constant. If it were, one would be able to conclude that the maps $\mathcal{F}(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}_x$ are all constant, since they would send both $U$ and the empty set to the same element. But this cannot happen, since the image of the maps $\mathcal{F}(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}_x$ should generate the target under joins.
This particular $\mathcal{A}$ is not locally presentable, however one can also find a locally presentable example by working with the category $\mathcal{A}'$ of small posets with countable joins and countable join preserving morphisms. The morphism of $\mathcal{A}$-valued sheaves $\mathcal{G} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ from above can also be regarded as a morphism of $\mathcal{A}'$ valued sheaves, and it turns out that the stalks in this setting are still given by $\lbrace 0 , 1 \rbrace$: this can be deduced from the case of $\mathcal{A}$ by using the fact that for every $U$ the posets $\mathcal{F}(U)$ and $\mathcal{G}(U)$ are equal to their own $\operatorname{Ind}_{\omega_1}$-completion.

Very nice example.  I was initially taken aback, thinking: But those are sheaves of posets, and we know that for sheaves of posets, isomorphism can be detected by stalks!  For others with the same confusion, the resolution is that the inclusion from (countably) sup-complete posets into posets doesn’t preserve colimits, so the stalks are different when computed in the sup-complete category — in particular, the stalk of $G$ collapses.  Giving that stalk computation more directly, we can see exactly how countable joins cause the collapse: [cont’d]

[cont’d] $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$Writing the stalk inclusions as $\alpha : G(U) \to G_0$, we have for any $V \subseteq U$ that $\alpha(V) = \bigvee_{n} \alpha(V) = \bigvee_{n} \alpha(V \cup (-\infty,-1/n) \cup (1/n,\infty)) = \alpha(\bigvee_n (V \cup (-\infty,-1/n) \cup (1/n,\infty))) =  \alpha (V \cup (\R \setminus {0}))$, and hence no information can be retained in the stalk beyond whether $0$ is in each “germ”.

Interesting! So perhaps the lesson here is that stalks should not be computed using the filtered colimits that already exist if they are not known to be well behaved. That it happens even for locally presentable categories means that failure of sheaf-locality does not prevent sheafification – we just cannot use the Godement comonad to calculate it (because we do not have comonadicity of sheaves over stalks in this case).

Here is a reformulation/generalisation of G. Stefanich's counterexample, showing that sheaf-locality can fail very dramatically once we leave the realm of locally finitely presentable categories.
More precisely:
Proposition.

There is an algebraic category $\mathcal{A}$ that (simultaneously) fails to be sheaf-local on every locally connected Hausdorff space $X$ with at least one open subset that is not closed.
($\mathcal{A}$ does not depend on $X$.)

For every uncountable regular cardinal $\kappa$, there is a $\kappa$-ary algebraic category $\mathcal{A}$ that (simultaneously) fails to be sheaf-local on every locally connected Hausdorff space $X$ of cardinality $< \kappa$ with at least one subset that is not closed.
($\mathcal{A}$ depends on $\kappa$ but not $X$.)


Proof.
Recall that the Sierpiński space $S$ is the topological space whose set of points is $\{ 0, 1 \}$ and whose open subsets are $\emptyset, \{ 1 \}, \{ 0, 1 \}$.
Almost by construction, there is a natural bijection between continuous maps $X \to S$ and open subsets of $X$, so we have a sheaf $\Omega$ on $X$ whose sections over an open $U \subseteq X$ are open subsets of $U$.
Similarly, there is a natural bijection between continuous maps $X \to 2$ and clopen subsets of $X$, so we have a sheaf $Q$ on $X$ whose sections over an open $U \subseteq X$ are the clopen subsets of $U$.
Furthermore, the continuous injective map $2 \to S$ gives rise to a subsheaf inclusion $Q \to \Omega$.
Now let $\mathcal{A}$ be the category of $\kappa$-ary join semilattices, i.e. posets in which every subset of cardinality $< \kappa$ has a least upper bound, and assume $\kappa$ is greater than the cardinality of $X$.
This is a $\kappa$-ary algebraic category (hence locally $\kappa$-presentable a fortiori).
Although $\mathcal{A}$ has filtered colimits, they are not preserved by the forgetful functor $\mathcal{A} \to \textbf{Set}$ if $\kappa > \aleph_0$.
This is the root cause of the failure of sheaf-locality for $\mathcal{A}$.
Let $N (x)$ be the filter of open neighbourhoods of $x$ in $X$.
There is a natural morphism $\Omega (U) \to \Omega (1)$ in $\mathcal{A}$ sending $V$ to $1$ if and only if $x \in V$, so we get a morphism $\varinjlim_{U : N (x)^\textrm{op}} \Omega (U) \to \Omega (1)$.
If $X$ is Hausdorff, this is an isomorphism: indeed, if $V \in \Omega (X)$ and $x \notin V$, then $V$ is the union of $< \kappa$ open $V_\alpha \subseteq V$ such that $x \notin \overline{V_\alpha} \subseteq X$; but if $V' \in \Omega (X)$ and $x \notin \overline{V'}$, then we can find $U \in N (x)$ with $U \cap V' = \emptyset$, so $V'$ must be identified with $\emptyset$ in the colimit, and hence $V$ is also identified with $\emptyset$ in the colimit.
(This argument would also work when we consider $\Omega$ as a sheaf of sets if $N (x)^\textrm{op}$ is $\kappa$-filtered.)
On the other hand, if $X$ is locally connected, then it is easy to see that $\varinjlim_{U : N (x)^\textrm{op}} Q (U) \cong Q (1)$, being a colimit of a cofinally constant diagram.
Thus, if $X$ is a locally connected Hausdorff space with at least one open subset that is not closed, then $Q_x \to \Omega_x$ is an isomorphism for every $x \in X$, but $Q \to \Omega$ is not an isomorphism.
The above proves the second claim of the proposition.
For the first claim, remove the cardinality restrictions and replace $\mathcal{A}$ with the category of complete join semilattices.　◼
